# Trying to solve a double integral under a slanted plane?

Tags: calculus

I want to find the volume under the slanted plane

$$f(x,y)=\frac{101}{1448}x + 56 $$

bounded by a circle with radius 7.7. I've used all the rules in polar coordinates to try and find this volume, but when I do it I get a volume defined by a cylinder with formula

$$ V=\pi r^2 h $$
where $h=56$ and $r=7.7$.

-- an IDENTICAL answer when they SHOULDN'T be the same since that plane is slanted and that cylinder assumes a horizontally flat top, they are different. They should be similar but NOT THE SAME. What am I doing wrong??

Is it because I can only work with symmetrical functions with polar coordinates?

EDIT: can someone answer the question with a formula in purely double integrals that can find the volume under that slanted plane?

Comment: Why do you want to use polar coordinates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are bounded in the plane by the disk $x^2+y^2 \leq (7.7)^2$ then this is your domain. You can set up the triple integral in cylidrical coordinates as follows:

$$\int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{7.7} r \int_{0}^{\frac{101}{1448} (7.7 \cos \theta) + 56} 1 \ dzdrd\theta$$

[image]

Comment: Does it have to be a triple integral? I cannot do a simple volume like this using a double integral?

Comment: The problem is, the top is slanted. What you can also do is find the volume of the cylinder with radius $7.7$ and height $56$ then subtract off from that the excess volume given by:  $$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{7.7} r \int_{\frac{101x}{1448} + 56}^{56} 1 \ dzdrd\theta$$  which seems like a lot of extra work.

Comment: Is the double integral $$2 \int ^\pi _0 \int ^{7.7} _0 (\frac{101}{1448} (r cos \theta ) +56)\, r \, dr \, d \theta  $$ not sufficient?

Comment: thanks very much - how would you parameterise the region for a double integral?

Comment: That's exactly the same integral. The only step that you've simplified is my first integral which is your first integrand. And the object is not symmetric about the x-axis, so you can just double, so change the ending integral limits back to $0,2\pi$.

Comment: I evaluated that double integral and it gave me teh same answer as the formula for a cylinder would. I even checked it on double integral calculators. Why is that? I got 10404.8, which is $\pi r^2 h$, cylinder volume, which is wrong. the double integral should be slightly less than a full cylinder because of the slant. how is this possible? (height is actually 55.86 but i rounded up in the question. if you use this height for the integral and for the cylinder formula theyre equal somehow?)

Comment: This is not the volume of a cylinder! The top is slanted. Of course you would get the same answer as the volume of a cylinder if you set the integral up as if that's what you wanted to find. Your integral calculates the volume of a cylinder of radius $7,7$ and heigh $56$ because you assume that a symmetry is at the $y$-axis. This is done when you wrote $$2\int_{0}^{\pi} \cdots$$

Comment: i see, how would I not assume symmetry? how to do it with double integrals then? do i set the boundaries of $\theta$ as $[0,2\pi]$ ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54069/discussion-between-m98b-pro-and-faraad-armwood).

Comment: You don't need a triple integral, however it would have started out as one, if you notice the innermost z integral easily evaluates to the function defining the slanted top of the cylinder, which you could have started with in the beginning as the integrand for a double integral

Comment: so can anyone answer the question with a formula in double integrals that can find the volume under that slanted plane?

Comment: No @Faraad, the problem is symmetric about the plane $y=0$ and, I presume because chance, it's reflected in the factor 2 and the **limits of the integral**

Comment: @RafaBudría, yes that is true of course, but the OP goes from $[0, \pi]$ when you should go from $[-\pi/2, \pi/2]$ and double!

Comment: @Faraad No, no. $y$ and $-y$ get the same value for $f$. He get the same volume as for a cylinder is because the slant is of no effect at all!!